# Why are vampires so afraid of the Volturi?

Tags: twilight

All the vampires in Twilight seem to have "respect" for the Volturi. Why are they so afraid of them? The Volturi don't have any special abilities. Reading your mind by holding your hand is not really harmful.

I know they have many disciples with interesting skills, but by themselves, what other specialties do they have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 1. There is strength in numbers

The Volturi are respected and feared partly because they are so numerous. Vampires can tend to be solitary creatures but sometimes band together in covens for support and security. The Volturi has arguably the largest and strongest coven around. In fact, the Volturi began to feel threatened by Carlisle's coven mostly because it had grown so large recently. They thought Carlisle might be planning to challenge them.

Besides their core members, the Volturi have many followers as can be seen in this image:

[image]

So it makes sense that, since vampire tend to live either alone or in smaller groups, most vampires respect and/or fear the Volturi and their large following.

---

## 2. They possess many powerful special abilities

In addition to their numbers, the many special abilities possessed by the Volturi also lead many to fear and respect them.

[Volturi](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Volturi) powers:

- [Aro](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Aro#Powers_and_abilities) and [Sulpicia](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Sulpicia#Powers_and_abilities:_tactile_telepathy) both have Tactile telepathy
- > [Marcus](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Marcus#Powers_and_abilities:_relationship_identification) has the ability to recognize the types of relationships between people and their strong and weak spots.
- > [Didyme](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Didyme#Powers_and_abilities:_happiness_induction) had the power to release an aura of happiness, which could bring joy to herself and everyone around her, freeing people from sadness and making them adore her.

Volturi Guard powers:

- [Chelsea](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Chelsea#Powers_and_abilities:_relationship_manipulation) has relationship manipulation
- [Jane](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Jane#Powers_and_abilities:_pain_illusion) can create illusions of intense pain
- [Alec](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Alec#Powers_and_abilities:_sensory_deprivation) has the power of sensory deprivation

Even the one's who don't a special power are still very menacing, for example:

- > [Caius](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Caius#Personality_and_traits) is very ambitious and can easily be considered the cruelest of all three leaders, and is seen as never extending mercy to anyone.

Comment: I would argue that you've got this backwards, that it's the special abilities (especially those of their followers Chelsea, Jane, and Alec) that make them so powerful, rather than their numbers.

Comment: @Donald.McLean "The Volturi are respected and feared __partly__ because they are so numerous". I was simply addressing each point separately. I address their many powerful abilities as my second point. I'll try to clarify though. :)